# Continuous Full GC - Java 8

Tags: java, linux, java-8, garbage-collection, huge-pages

Cross Posting from [openJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-use/2017-October/002708.html).

Why was **Full GC (Allocation Failure)** or for that matter a GC being triggered even when Eden Space was (almost) empty. I can see Metaspace being full, but then a GC due to that should have had **Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)** and *NOT* Allocation Failure as the reason.

This went on for roughly 9hrs. Any thoughts?

```
2017-10-28T20:30:32.207+0000: 382100.678: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(253952K)] [ParOldGen: 146546K->146546K(348160K)] 146546K->146546K(602112K), [Metaspace: 45647K->45647K(1091584K)], 0.1865769 secs] [Times: user=0.87 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
2017-10-28T20:30:32.401+0000: 382100.872: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 160K->0K(253952K)] [ParOldGen: 146546K->146547K(348160K)] 146706K->146547K(602112K), [Metaspace: 45647K->45647K(1091584K)], 0.1871330 secs] [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
2017-10-28T20:30:32.592+0000: 382101.064: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(253952K)] [ParOldGen: 146547K->146547K(348160K)] 146547K->146547K(602112K), [Metaspace: 45647K->45647K(1091584K)], 0.1852237 secs] [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.01, real=0.18 secs]
2017-10-28T20:30:32.786+0000: 382101.257: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 192K->0K(253952K)] [ParOldGen: 146547K->146558K(348160K)] 146739K->146558K(602112K), [Metaspace: 45647K->45647K(1091584K)], 0.1879624 secs] [Times: user=0.89 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
2017-10-28T20:30:32.979+0000: 382101.450: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(253952K)] [ParOldGen: 146558K->146552K(348160K)] 146558K->146552K(602112K), [Metaspace: 45647K->45647K(1091584K)], 0.2331467 secs] [Times: user=1.15 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs]
```

Exception in std_out:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
```

Similar stack trace is also observed for a plain object allocation instructions.

System Details:

- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 16:36:53 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
- This application was using AnonHugePages (THP)

Comment: Possibly you are allocating / trying to allocate *really large objects*; i.e. objects that are larger than the max threshold for allocating then in Eden space..

Comment: @StephenC This process was working fine for 50hrs (with good load) and then all of a sudden it started failing. Max size of a single object that's being allocation by this JVM is around 1MB.

Comment: `java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate` instrument the callsite of that to see how many bytes it's trying to allocate.

Comment: @the8472 we can see that for normal object allocation too I.e not ByteBuffer. Plain *new Class()*

Comment: Could it be that your OS is actually out of memory?

Comment: @DidierL Per our system monitoring, we had 10GB+ free memory at that point.

Comment: It could be that a cosmic ray has changed some bit in your system's memory.  This *smells* like a JVM bug, but unless you can reproduce it or provide more relevant info (like a full crash dump), it would be impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @StephenC lol.. current theory we’re working with is to blame Transparent Huge Pages (THP).

Comment: Do you have any real evidence to support that theory?

Comment: @StephenC Nothing re-producible as of now. Will share if we can re-produce something with certainty.